# Applying tooltip on mouse hover

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm putting an image on html5 canvas.

```
myString = '<img id="img1" class="link1" src = 'img/icon1.png'></img>';
            $('#main1' ).append(myString);
            $('#main1' + '-link1').fadeIn('slow'); 

            $(".link1").click(function () {
                window.location.href = url1;
            });

$(".link1").hover(function () {
                $('#myDiv').show();
            }, function () {
                $('#myDiv').hide();
            });
```

The div is :

```
<div id="myDiv" style="display:none;border: 1px solid black;width: 10px;height:5px;padding: 1px;">
    <p>Hello</p>
</div>
```

Now, on mouse hover the div appears at end of the page. I need it to appear just below the image. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That depends on the positioning of your 'myDiv' div.

You could just use the `<img title="my tooltip text" />` if it's just text in your tooltip.

Comment: `alt` shows the alternate text if image not found..not `Tooltip`

Answer (score 2):

You can use pageX , pageY from event object to position the div  on below the image .

Please try this link to get the solution  http://jsfiddle.net/ZpGS3/14/ .

Answer (score 1):

You may try a jQuery plugin called TipTip:

http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/tiptip-jquery-plugin

You'll see it's very easy to use and the design is quite great :).

You can go to the link and have a try to see if you like it or not.

Considering your example, in order to display the TipTip's tooltip, you'll simply have to do the following:

- Include TipTip's CSS and JS file references
- Put some JS: `$("#img1").tipTip();`
- Put your tooltip's content inside the `title` option of your image:

For example: `<img id="img1" title="<p>Hello</p>"/>`

Answer (score 1):

To apply Tooltip on mouseover you should use

```
$('#img1').mouseover(function(){
$(this).attr('title','MY Image Title');
});
```